# Query for a timecard database

Tags: t-sql

I have a timecard table for staff to clock in/out, the layout is as follow:

```
employeeID  Clock-in DateTime   Clock Type
1004        24/09/2013 13:08    in
1004        25/09/2013 00:50    out
1005        24/09/2013 12:08    in
1005        25/09/2013 03:55    out
2003        24/09/2013 10:06    in
2003        24/09/2013 15:42    out
2003        24/09/2013 17:33    in
2003        24/09/2013 22:17    out
```

How can I get it to be like:

```
Date        employeeID  Clock-in            Clock-out           time worked (in hours to 2 decimal place)
24/09/2013  1004        24/09/2013 13:08    25/09/2013 00:50    xx.xx
24/09/2013  1005        24/09/2013 12:08    25/09/2013 03:55    xx.xx
24/09/2013  2003        24/09/2013 10:06    24/09/2013 15:42    xx.xx
24/09/2013  2003        24/09/2013 17:33    24/09/2013 22:17    xx.xx
```

note:

1. employee can have multiple clock in / out (i.e. morning / afternoon, night shift)
2. the date runs from `04:00:00` to `03:59:59` (i.e. in above example, all classified as `24/09/2013`)
3. how can I handle records with no clock-out? can I set something like if `null`, time equals to next date `03:59:59`?

Thanks in advance.

I updated with the following with jods suggestion:

Example of 3 sets of in/out records

```
EmployeeID  CardDate            PunchType
1000        21/09/2013 07:43    in
1000        21/09/2013 11:29    out
1000        21/09/2013 12:39    in
1000        21/09/2013 20:37    out
1000        21/09/2013 21:58    in
1000        22/09/2013 00:16    out
```

Your query returns

```
Date        EmployeeID  clockInTime clockOutTime
21/09/2013  1000        07:43:57    00:16:22
21/09/2013  1000        21:58:40    11:29:22
```

Comment: Is there not a PK on this table?  Or can a given employee not clock in/out inside a minute - rendering the entire record unique.

Comment: and which version of sqlserver are you using ? It DOES make a difference

Comment: There is a primary key in the table, however it is somehow hashed. the clock/in and clock/out is in second, therefore every record is unique

Comment: We are using SQL server 2008 standard r2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use SQL SERVER 2005 and above. You can try this

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT
   [employeeID]
    ,ti.ClockIn
    ,ClockOut = (SELECT MIN(t.ClockIn) 
                 FROM timecard t 
                 WHERE ti.employeeID = t.employeeID 
                 AND t.Type = 'out' 
                 AND t.ClockIn > ti.ClockIn
                 AND t.ClockIn < DATEADD(hour, 24 + 4 , CAST(CAST(ti.ClockIn AS DATE) AS datetime))
                )  
    ,NextDayLimit = DATEADD(SECOND, -1, DATEADD(hour, 24 + 4 , CAST(CAST(ti.ClockIn AS DATE) AS datetime)))
FROM timecard ti
WHERE Type = 'in'
)
SELECT 
    employeeID,
    ClockIn,
    ISNULL(ClockOut, NextDayLimit) AS ClockOut,
    CAST(DATEDIFF(minute, ClockIn, ISNULL(ClockOut, NextDayLimit))/60.0 AS NUMERIC(19,2)) AS TimeWorked
from cte
ORDER BY    employeeID, ClockIn
```

Comment: I tried your solution, it works fine with the staff with up to 2 clockin/clockout (4 records), however I have one staff with 3 set of clockin/out, and there is a mis-match in the in and out records. I have put some sample raw data and the result set returned for your reference

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL 2012, here's the basic idea using LEAD:

```
SELECT 
   ROUND(clockIn) as [date],
   employeeId,
   clockIn as clockInTime,
   LEAD(clockIn) OVER (PARTITION BY employeeId, ROUND(clockIn) ORDER BY clockIn) as clockOutTime
FROM TimeCard
WHERE clockType = 'in'
```

You can then get the time by doing the difference between clock in and clock out times.

There are lots of corner cases, not all handled here:

- can a work period span midnight?
- what if the first clock-in is of type 'out'?
- what if there is two 'in' or two 'out' in a row?

The case where there is no clock out *is* handled, though. As the last row of a partition would have a LEAD value of NULL.

Here's a more robust option that works in SQL 2005:

```
WITH NumberedClockIn AS (
  SELECT 
    ROUND(clockIn) as [date],
    employeeId,
    clockIn as clockTime,
    clockType,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY employeeId, ROUND(clockIn) ORDER BY clockIn) as rn
  FROM TimeCard
)
SELECT 
  IN.[date], 
  IN.employeeId, 
  IN.clockTime as clockInTime,
  OUT.clockTime as clockOutTime
FROM NumberedClockIn IN
LEFT OUTER JOIN NumberedClockIn OUT
  ON IN.[date] = OUT.[date]
 AND IN.employeeId = OUT.employeeID
 AND IN.rn + 1 = OUT.rn
WHERE IN.clockType = 'in'
  AND OUT.clockType = 'out'
```

It's more complex and less efficient, but more robust in the face of invalid 'in' and 'out' sequences. Then again, the way it handles invalid sequences may or may not be the behavior that you actually want.